# Nano: how to obtain syntax highlighting?

Tags: terminal, bash

I have a default installation of `nano` under `/usr/bin/`, and I am trying to make `nano` highlight the bash scripting language code.

I have been searching around, but I had no success: I got always some errors, or simply doesn't work. For example, I have tried to download the following repository from Github `github.com/nanorc/nanorc.git` with the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/nanorc/nanorc.git
```

and then follow the steps in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/181049), but I have had errors because some command inside the files are not recognised. In particular, if I add this line `include ~/nanorc/shell.nanorc` to my file `~/.nanorc`, where the file `shell.nanorc`contains:

```
syntax "sh" "\.sh$" "\.bash$" "bashrc$" "bash_profile$"
header "^#!.*/(env +)?(ba|k|pdk)?sh[-0-9_]*( |$)"

FUNCTION: "^[A-Za-z0-9_+-]+[[:space:]]*\(\)"
KEYWORD:  "\<(case|do|done|elif|else|esac|fi|for|function|if)\>"
KEYWORD:  "\<(in|select|then|time|until|while)\>"
FUNCTION: "\<(echo|exit|export|let|local|read|return|set|shift|umask|unset)\>"
FUNCTION: "\<(source)\>"
OPERATOR: "[{}()<>!=&|;`$]|\\|\[|\]|-(eq|ne|gt|lt|ge|le|s|n|z)\>"
STRING:   ""(\\.|[^"])*""
VARIABLE: "\$\{?[A-Za-z0-9_!@#$*?-]+\}?|`[^`]*`"
STRING:   "'(\\.|[^'])*'"
ESCAPE:   "\\.?"
+HASHCOMMENT
+TODO
+LINT
```

It seems that these previous commands, such `STRING`, `ESCAPE`, etc, are not recognised.

How would you set syntax highlighting for nano, at least for bash?

Comment: What happens if you copy the text into ~/.nanorc and not use an include?

Answer (score 3):

Install the latest version of `nano` with `homebrew`:

1. Install homebrew: https://brew.sh/
2. Install nano: `brew install nano`
3. Add this line to `~/.nanorc`. That directory has all the syntax highlighting definition files.

   ```
   include "/usr/local/share/nano/*.nanorc"
   ```

Comment: For Apple Silicon this needs to be `include "/opt/homebrew/share/nano/*.nanorc"`

Answer (score 1):

From the Nanorc(5) man file:

> The configuration file accepts a series of set and unset commands, which  can be used  to  configure  nano on startup without using the command line options.  **Additionally, the *syntax*, *color*, and *icolor* keywords are used to  define  syntax  highlighting rules for different text patterns.**  nano will read one command per line.

Your nanorc lacks that.

From the git read me from that repo:

> **Why do I get weird errors when running nano < 2.1.5 on *BSD systems?**
>   In order to reliably highlight keywords, this projects makes heavy use of the GNU regex word boundary extensions (\< and >). BSD implementations also have these extensions but use a different, incompatible syntax ([[:<:]] and [[:>:]]). Since version 2.1.5, nano can automatically translate the GNU syntax to BSD syntax at run-time, but for the benefit of people running a pre-2.1.5 version of nano on OS X or *BSD, the .nanorc file itself can be translated by installing with make BSDREGEX=1.

What is happening is that **you did not actually follow the full install commands**. If you cloned the git, cd'd into the directory, and ran make install, your syntax files would look different. For one, the default version of **nano** on OS X (I'm on 10.10.5 Mavericks) is **nano 2.0.6**. It does not support the **header** in syntax in this older version. The makefile for the git repo would remove that. And it would add in the color options.

You have 3 options.

1. Ensure you have the OS X command line tools (or full X Code)
   installed and run all of the install commands.
2. use precompiled nanorc syntax files compatible with the preinstalled nano 2.0.6 with BSD regex.
3. Install a newer nano, and use the nanorc that come with the full install.

As a bonus, I found and edited a single nanorc for sh/bash. Edit as you like:

```
syntax "sh" "\.sh$" "\.bash$" "bashrc$" "bash_profile$"
icolor brightgreen "^[0-9A-Z_]+\(\)"
color blue "[[:<:]](case|do|done|elif|else|esac|exit|fi|for|function|if|in|local|read|return|select|shift|then|time|until|while)[[:>:]]"
color green "(\{|\}|\(|\)|\;|\]|\[|`|\\|\$|<|>|!|=|&|\|)"
color green "-[Ldefgruwx][[:>:]]"
color green "-(eq|ne|gt|lt|ge|le|s|n|z)[[:>:]]"
color brightblue "[[:<:]](cat|cd|chmod|chown|cp|echo|env|export|grep|install|let|ln|make|mkdir|mv|rm|sed|set|tar|touch|umask|unset)[[:>:]]"
icolor brightred "\$\{?[0-9A-Z_!@#$*?-]+\}?"
color cyan "(^|[[:space:]])#.*$"
color brightmagenta ""(\\.|[^"])*"" "'(\\.|[^'])*'"
color ,green "[[:space:]]+$"
```